# Is there anyway to obtain a triangle from BoxShape?

Tags: flutter

Is there anyway to create a triangle from `BoxDecoration`'s shape property?

If not, what would I have to do to `Container` to obtain a triangle (preferably an equilateral or isosceles triangle)? In CSS, there was a method to do this by using some transparent borders, would love an analog in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Clipper widget is what you need, it basically cuts out some parts of the container

Comment: this not an answer, post your code, show masterpiece